# Barcode scanner in zxing example

Tags: ios, ios4, repository, augmented-reality, zxing

Is anyone able to tell me where i might be able to find an example of the barcode scanner 'zxing'?. Also i have found the following link : http://zxing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/iphone/  but i'm not sure on how to download the whole iphone directory

Comment: try http://zxing.googlecode.com/files/ZXing-1.7.zip there is a objc directory :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the whole [archive](http://zxing.googlecode.com/files/ZXing-1.7.zip).
Open the folder and find the example project in **iPhone\ScanTest** folder

Comment: link is not active